# Data not rendered on the screen while looping in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am developing an angular2 app and want to display the value of data returned by my service. I am able to see the data when I do a loop and display it via interpolation i.e double curly brace brackets. However I need to assign it to properties of the a googlemap api . I don't think that data is rendered through the normal loop that doesn't use interpolation. How to I ascertain this ? Below is my code. Please note Latitude and Longitude are type number.

The data is rendered correctly using this piece of code

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data">

        <p>{{d.Latitude}}</p>
        <p>{{d.Longitude}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I think nothing gets rendered using this piece of code. The problem is I need to assign it to property of a third party api. Test1 and Test2 takes number as a value.

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="0"
                  [longitude]="0"
                  [zoom]="1">
     <div *ngFor="let d of data">


         <sebm-google-map-marker *ngIf=  "d.Latitude"
                                 [latitude]="d.Latitude"
                                 [longitude]="d.Longitude">

         </sebm-google-map-marker>

     </div>
 </sebm-google-map>
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. *What* are you trying to bind that data into? There's no element there. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Here you go, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp
html attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property binding would only work on element level where you want to pass data between components, as you intended to work property binding on inside element content it would not evaluate property binding it consider as text and will print as is on Page.

Here in this case you wanted to pass it to third party component, so property binding should be place on element like below.

```
<third-party-component [test1]="d.data1" [test2]="d.data2">
</third-party-component>
```

Comment: My code is the same as yours except I have put it in LI tag. However in my actual implementation its in the thirdpary component tag.  The assignment is the same as mine. My question is how do I ascertain that "d.data1" has value.

Comment: I don't gwt you

Comment: @Tom your code is not the same; here the bindings are inside the element definition. Yours are in the element content, which won't work.

Comment: <sebm-google-map [latitude]="0"
                      [longitude]="0"
                      [zoom]="1">
         <div *ngFor="let d of data">
           

             <sebm-google-map-marker *ngIf=  "d.Latitude"
                                     [latitude]="d.Latitude"
                                     [longitude]="d.Longitude">

             </sebm-google-map-marker>

         </div>
     </sebm-google-map>

Comment: Where does the The code that you have suggested above needs to be put. Is it in the for loop

Comment: @Tom please always ask question with appropriate explanation.. now could you please update your OP with your template? and my answer is just saying that the inner ngFor should be changed to what I explained in answer, and code is related to the same :)

Comment: Hi Pankaj, sorry for not being clear. OP ? Do you mean  I need to update the post with my actual template

Comment: @Tom I mean you should update your question, so that by reading it people should understand what;s happening with your code?

Comment: Hi Pankaj I have updated my question. I tried to be avoid too much description but guess it didnt help. Hope it is clear now

Comment: I am sure there is no value coming from my for loop in which i am assigning to the api properties. Because if i hardcode values it shows it properly on the screen

Comment: @Tom is it thing `d.Latitude` has 0 value? because in that case `*ngIf` will not allow to render `sebm-google-map-marker` component at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130283/discussion-between-tom-and-pankaj-parkar).